# Unable to run Edge in IE Compatibility mode on the Jenkins server

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, ie-compatibility-mode

I have the following code that launches Edge in IE Compatibility mode:

```
            case EDGE_COMPATIBILITY: {
                logMessage(MessType.INFO, "Running Edge under compatibility mode.");
                
                InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                
                ieOptions.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains();
                ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
                ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
                ieOptions.destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();
                
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", projectLoc + "\\src\\externaljars\\selenium\\edgedriver\\iedriverserver.exe");
                
                try {
                    logMessage(MessType.INFO, "About to create 'webdr'");
                    webdr = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
                    
                    logMessage(MessType.INFO, "Sleeping for 10 seconds.");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    logMessage(MessType.INFO, "Done sleeping ...");
                    
                    webdr.manage().window().maximize();

                    Thread.sleep(1000);     

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                break;
            }
```

This works great when running the automated scripts locally, here is what it looks like:

```
TITLE Executing Method launchBrowser  Time: [1:38:34PM]
INFO TEMP LOG MESSAGE : Data Source: DATABASE  Browser: EDGE_COMPATIBILITY URL: null
INFO TEMP LOG MESSAGE :  Browser: EDGE_COMPATIBILITY
INFO Running Edge under compatibility mode.
INFO About to create 'webdr'
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
4.7.0.0
Listening on port 23537
Only local connections are allowed
INFO Sleeping for 10 seconds.
INFO Done sleeping ...
```

but when I try to run the same code from a Jenkins server, I get the following exception error:

```
14:02:26    [testng] TITLE Executing Method launchBrowser  Time: [4:2:26PM]
14:02:26    [testng] INFO TEMP LOG MESSAGE : Data Source: DATABASE  Browser: EDGE_COMPATIBILITY URL: null
14:02:26    [testng] INFO TEMP LOG MESSAGE :  Browser: EDGE_COMPATIBILITY
14:02:26    [testng] INFO Running Edge under compatibility mode.
14:02:26    [testng] INFO About to create 'webdr'
14:02:27    [testng] Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
14:02:27    [testng] 4.7.0.0
14:02:27    [testng] Listening on port xxxxxx
14:02:27    [testng] Only local connections are allowed
14:05:28    [testng] org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
14:05:28    [testng] Host info: host: 'xxxxxxxxxx', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
14:05:28    [testng] Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
14:05:28    [testng] System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.11'
14:05:28    [testng] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
14:05:28    [testng] Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, se:ieOptions: {ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, se:ieOptions: {ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true}}}]
14:05:28    [testng] Capabilities {}
14:05:28    [testng]    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
```

What is even more interesting is that if I log onto the Jenkins server to see what's going on, then I don't get the exception error.  It is as though attaching a screen output ***completes*** the instantiation process.

Does anyone know whether this is a Jenkins limitation?  Or are there any other InternetOptions that I should be using.

Comment: IE, or Edge? Because those are completely different browsers. (And if you _really_ mean IE: that browser was officially discontinued by Microsoft in June of 2022. All in-support versions of Windows come with Edge)

Comment: Edge allows you to run IE under compatibility mode (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=java).  This is Microsoft's way of providing backward compatibility for applications that can only run under IE.

Comment: Then please edit your post and title to reflect the fact that you're using Edge, set to IE compatibility more. Right now your title and post sound like you're straight up using IE.

Comment: Yes, good catch.  Title updated.

Comment: You're still saying you're running IE, though. I've edited your title and post to say you're running Edge, in IE compatibility mode, instead.

Comment: In which user context is that PowerShell code running? Jenkins runs as LocalSystem by default, which behaves differently than a regular user account, where a browser is supposed to run. Furthermore, Jenkins as a service runs in session 0 isolation, so it can't launch interactive programs such as a browser. There are ways around that, e. g. create an additional Jenkins node that is launched as a regular user by a scheduled task. Run that PowerShell script on this node by specifying it via `agent` or `node` directives.

Comment: The Jenkins job was not setup as a service since you're right, it did not allow for user interaction.  We have a service account login that launched that job and it remains logged on in perpetuity.  I don't think it was setup as a PowerShell, but I could be wrong.  I didn't set it up.